# Click Event not fired in User Control when multiple instances are created

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I've a user control with 2 labels and two textboxes. When the label is clicked the  textbox's visible prop is set to true. Here's the code I've used:

```
    private void label_Heading_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label_Heading.Visible = false;
        textBox_Heading.Text = label_Heading.Text;
        textBox_Heading.Visible = true;
        textBox_Heading.Focus();
    }
```

After the textbox lose focus, it's visible prop is set to false and the label is updated with the text. Code:

```
    private void textBox_Heading_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox_Heading.Visible = false;
        if(textBox_Heading.Text != "")
            label_Heading.Text = textBox_Heading.Text;
        label_Heading.Visible = true;
    }
```

The code to create user controls on click:

```
    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TaskCard _taskCard = new TaskCard(++TOTAL_ITEM_COUNT, PanelName);
        panel_DeletedItem.Controls.Add(_taskCard);
        panel_DeletedItem.Refresh();
    }
```

These code work fine when a single user control of this type is added to a panel. But if I add more than one, the code works only for the first user control, but it wont work for the new ones, although the event is fired for every user control. What am I missing here? Please suggest.

If I add a mbox to this code, the mbox is displayed for any control, but the rest of the code won't work, except for the first one.

```
    private void label_Heading_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test"); // this will display, but the rest of the code is not executed or changes are not visible, i.e., the teboxes are not displayed even if I click the labels
        label_Heading.Visible = false;
        textBox_Heading.Text = label_Heading.Text;
        textBox_Heading.Visible = true;
        textBox_Heading.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: Did you make the internal Controls of your UC `public` and subscribed to their events in the Form class? Wrong method. It's the UC container that needs to provide means to access its internal members from the outside in a controlled manner: you need to raise events from the UC, creating and exposing public events that other classes can subscribe to, thus each UC handles interactions with its own internal members. -- The Form class (for example), can subscribe to these public events using the same handle. If needed, the `sender` object references the UC that raised the event(s).

Comment: @Jimi, The controls of my UC are not public, neither the methods. If I wanna invoke a private method tagged to the click event of a label in the UC, does it matter where the UC is placed? I mean, if I put it in a Form>>Table Layout>>Panel, do I need to do anything extra to invoke the method in UC when the label in it is clicked?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter what the parent is. You should post the definition of your UC. If those events are subscribed to internally (by the UC class), the behavior you're describing can only make sense if the Fields that reference the Controls are static (or *something else* is).